# $resource.save is not functioning

Tags: json, angularjs

I am a novice developer of angularJs.
Working on some tutorials and facing the following problem now.
This is my view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="eventsApp">
<head>
    <title>Event Registry</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

</head>
<body ng-cloak>
<div id="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li> <a href="/app/addEvent.html"> Add Event </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div ng-controller="EditEventController">
       <div class="container">
                <h1>New Event</h1>
           <hr/>
           <form name="editEventForm">
               <fieldset>
                   <label for="eventname">Event Name :</label>
                   <input id="eventname" type="text" ng-model="event.name" placeholder="Enter your Event Name"/>
                   <label for="eventdate">Event Date :</label>
                   <input id="eventdate" type="text" ng-model="event.date" placeholder="format is (dd/mm/yy)..."/>
                   <label for="eventtime">Event Time : </label>
                   <input id="eventtime" type="text" ng-model="event.time" placeholder="Enter the start time and end time"/>
                   <label for="eventlocation">Event Location :</label>
                   <input id="eventlocation" type="text" ng-model="event.location.address" placeholder="Enter the location of the event"/>
                   <br/>
                   <input id="eventstate" type="text" class="input-small" ng-model="event.location.state" placeholder="Enter the state of the location of the event"/>
                   <input id="eventcountry" type="text" class="input-small" ng-model="event.location.country" placeholder="Enter the country of the location of the event"/>
                   <br/>
                   <label for="eventImageUrl">Image Url:</label>
                   <input id="eventImageUrl" type="url" class="input input-xlarge" ng-model="event.imageUrl" placeholder="enter the image url"/>

               </fieldset>
               <img ng-src="{{event.imageUrl}}" src=""/>
               <br/>
               <br/>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="savestatus(event,editEventForm)">Save</button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>

           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/EventData.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/GravatarUrlBuilder.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/EventController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/EditEventController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/EditProfileController.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/filters.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

and my controller is

```
angular.module('eventsApp.controllers').controller('EditEventController',function EditEventController($scope,eventData){
    $scope.event={};
    $scope.savestatus=function(event,form){
        if(form.$valid){
            eventData.save(event).
            then(function(response){
                    console.log("success :",response);
                },
            function(response){
                console.log("failure:",response);
            });


        };
    } ;
     $scope.reset=function(){
         window.location='../app/EventList.html';
     }
});
```

and the app.js file is

```
angular.module('eventsApp', [ 'ngSanitize' ,'eventsApp.controllers',  'eventsApp.services','ngResource'
 ])
```

and the services file i am using is:

```
angular.module('eventsApp.services').factory('eventData',function($resource,$q){
       var resource= $resource('data/eventData/:id.json',{id:'@id'});
    return{
        getEventItem:function(){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
              resource.get({id:1},

               function(eventItem){
                  deferred.resolve(eventItem);
            },
               function(response){
                    deferred.reject(response);
               });
            return deferred.promise;
        } ,
           save:function(event){

                 var deferred=$q.defer();
               event.id=999;
               resource.save(event,
               function(response){
                     deferred.resolve(response);
               },
               function(response){
                   deferred.reject(response);
               }
               );
               return deferred.promise;
           }
    };
}


) ;
```

When i am trying to save the input text details on click of the savestatus()  button 
I am unable to save them as a json file on the disk as shown in the tutorial I am referring to..
Whenever I have tried to save it I am getting the following error...

```
POST http://localhost:8000/app/data/eventData/999.json 501 (Not Implemented) angular.js:7073
failure: Object {data: "", status: 501, headers: function, config: Object}
```

Comment: `status 501` is server code problem....look deeper into the request in browser console to see that params sent are what you expect and do server side debugging   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Did you find a fix? I'm having this problem as well.

Comment: Replace your copy of web-server.js with the one at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joeeames/AngularFundamentalsFiles/master/web-server.js - for some reason the .ZIP file on that site doesn't contain the correct version of the file.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem and solved my case. Here's how I did:

1. You have to modify your back-end (in my case: [web-server.js](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/scripts/web-server.js)
   from angular-seed project, running with NodeJs) in order
   to accept 'POST' method requests.
2. Then, when a POST request will be sent, you
       must catch it (a simple 'if' would do the trick) and call a function
       to handle it.
3. Finally, you have to write this function which will
       catch the request data and do what you want with it (e.g. create a
       JSON file and copy the data into it).

If you're also using NodeJs and maybe the web-server.js from angular-seed, here's what I've done : [modified Web-server.js](https://github.com/glepretre/angular-seed/commit/9108d8e4bf6f70a5145b836ebeae0db3f29593d7#diff-d169b27b604606d4223bd5d85cad7da1)

Hope it will help you or someone else to avoid 501 errors!

Comment: I am doing the same tutorial and I had the same problem, the suggested fix (modify web-server.js) did the trick. Thank you for that.

Comment: Dude, you rock.  This is one of some many 'Angularisms' that some of us have to work around and through. Thanks so much for sharing your work.