# Unable to POST data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a small application for fetching data from one JSON file and posting it to another JSON file. I am using AngularJS and `ngResource` and `$http` services to achieve the functionality.

I was able to read data using `GET` method, but `POST` is not posting data to my another JSON file.

Below are my controller and services definitions:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var boookbAppControllers = angular.module('boookbAppControllers', []);

boookbAppControllers.controller('boookbAppCtrl', ['$scope','$http','Book',
  function($scope,$http,Book) {

    $scope.way=["Normal","$http","RestFul"]



    $http.get('data/books.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.b1 = data;

    $scope.addBook1=function(){ 


        $http.post('data/newbooks.json',{ "catalogRefIds" : $scope.books[0].title,   "productId" : $scope.books[0].author}).then(function(response,status){
        $scope.a=status;
        alert($scope.a);

        });
    } 

    $scope.b2 = Book.query();


    $scope.newBookName="";
    $scope.userBook="";
    $scope.userBookAuthor="";
    $scope.newBookAuthor="";
    $scope.bookData={};

    $scope.addBook=function(){
    $scope.userBook=$scope.newBookName;
    $scope.userBookAuthor=$scope.newBookAuthor; 

    Book.add({},$scope.bookData);

    }
  });
  }]);


'use strict';

/* Services */

var boookbAppServices = angular.module('boookbAppServices', ['ngResource']);

boookbAppServices.factory('Book', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('data/:bookId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{bookId:'books'}, isArray:true},
      add: {method:'POST',params:{bookId:'books'},isArray: true}    
    });
  }]);
```

I checked traces of `POST` data and no data was being sent.

Comment: You cannot simply `POST` to a file. You need some kind of server-side scripting that will handle this. What does your backend setup look like?

Comment: You might be in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19618010/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do by POSTing to a .json file.  That being said, assuming you are actually handling the POST request server side and not seeing any data, this is most likely the issue:

Angular posts data differently than jQuery, for example - it sends it over as `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  So, in PHP for example, if you check `$_POST['key']` it won't find it.  Your options there are either handle it server side:

```
$_JSON = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_JSON = json_decode($_JSON, TRUE);
echo $_JSON['key'];
```

Or you can transform it to form-data it client-side:

```
boookbAppControllers.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post  = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data) {
      if (data === undefined) return data;
      var clonedData = clone(data);
      for (var property in clonedData)
         //you could do this with hasOwnProperty probably,
         //but this works unless you prepend variable keys
         //with $
         if (property.substr(0, 1) == '$')
           delete clonedData[property];

      return $.param(clonedData);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at $http.post syntax: we need to pass data with the keyword **data** encapsulating actual data.

```
    $http.post('data/newbooks.json', data : { "catalogRefIds" : $scope.books[0].title,   "productId" : $scope.books[0].author}).then(function(response,status){
            $scope.a=status;
            alert($scope.a);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

When posting JSON data use **Content-Type** as **text/plain**, tried and tested in angular 1.5.11

```
$http({
  method : 'POST',
  url : 'http://example.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  },
  data : JSON.stringify({data})
})
```