# AngularJS problems with $resource and web servers

Tags: json, node.js, angularjs, post, resources

I have been testing this code for 2 months, it is the first exercise in my tutorial to learn AngularJS.
The challenge is to count all .json files in a folder and increment it with 1 so that when I save another json file it will always have a higher ID then the previous one. I am having lots of trouble with web servers, first of all NodeJS does not seem to allow JSON posts in its standard configuration. So I have found a modified web-server.js from stockoverflow from a different question:
[$resource.save is not functioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618010/resource-save-is-not-functioning)
https://github.com/glepretre/angular-seed/commit/9108d8e4bf6f70a5145b836ebeae0db3f29593d7#diff-d169b27b604606d4223bd5d85cad7da1 I have also tried the web-server.js that came with the tutorial: 
http://pastebin.com/Ckfh4jvD that seemed to work better. WAMP also did not work I could not get Apache to allow JSON posts.

Problem is the web-server posts the json or sees the json as an object not as an array, even though I have used "isArray: true" and I use .query() instead of .get(). And I have tried many other things like transformResponse: []. I need the array to get .length to work! Also sometimes it GETS an array and POSTS an object which it later reads as object again it is getting really weird.

The code works sometimes as posted or sometimes I need to change :id to :id.json, usually this means the server is retrieving it as an object again which is not what I wan but this differs between the 2 nodeJS servers.

```
.factory('eventData', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
            var resource = $resource('/app/data/event/:id', {id: '@id'}, {"getAll": {method:    "GET", isArray: true}});
            var number = resource.query();
            console.log(number);
            return {
                getEvent: function () {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    resource.get({id: 1},
                    function (event) {
                        deferred.resolve(event);
                    },
                            function (response) {
                                deferred.reject(response);
                            });
                    return deferred.promise;
                },
                save: function (event) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    event.id = number.length;
                    resource.save(event,
                            function (response) {
                                deferred.resolve(response);

                            },
                            function (response) {
                                deferred.reject(response);
                            }
                    );
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            };
        }]);
```

EDIT: This seems to work better however I need to figure out how to put an .then() into this service?

```
.factory('eventData', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
            var resource = $resource('/app/data/event/:id.json',
                {id: '@id'}, {method: "getTask", q: '*' },
                {'query': { method: 'get'}});
            var number = resource.query();
```